# Multiple touch screens

Tags: touch, screen

I have 4 Dell 2314t screens connected to a HP ProDesk 600 G1 SFF. 2 screens are connected to the internal 2 display port connections. the 2nd two are connected to a 2nd graphic card with 2 display ports. When extending the screens to all four screens the touch from screen 1 and 2 are registered only on screen one. The same on screen 3 and 4, only on screen 3. Is there a third party application which can handle this. I want the touch individually on each screen connected to 1 PC? Or is it absolutely necessary to have a graphic adapter with four connections in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was this.

1.Go to Control Panel and search for "Touch".
2.Click "Tablet PC Settings" 
3.Click "Setup..." to the right of "Configure your pen and touch displays" 
4.Choose "Touch Input..." 
5.Hit the "Enter" key until you see the instructions appear on your actual touch monitor.  Touch the screen and it will say something like "Hit enter to move to the next step".